# Switch statement without jump table

Tags: c, switch-statement, jump-table

Is it possible to use a switch statement without a jump table? GCC creates stupid (and in my case unusable) jump tables which I want to avoid.

Comment: can you elaborate your question a bit more? example scenario.

Comment: What do you find distasteful about the jump table GCC creates for you? Are you sure fighting the compiler is what you need to do to achieve your goal?

Comment: @Santa on some platforms (e.g. arm) for jump tables a builtin is used (e.g. `__gnu_thumb1_case_sqi`) which is not included when `-nostdlib` or `-nodefaultlibs` is specified. So the jump table effectively generates code that does not work when not eventually linked against something providing `__gnu_thumb1_case_sqi`. I found that distasteful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

**-fno-jump-tables**

Do not use jump tables for switch statements even where it would be more efficient than other code generation strategies. This option is of use in conjunction with -fpic or -fPIC for building code that forms part of a dynamic linker and cannot reference the address of a jump table. On some targets, jump tables do not require a GOT and this option is not needed.